# Ruby FileUtils.mkdir error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a program to make about 100 copies of a folder, each with a different name but in the same directory. Here is the code I have so far:

```
require 'fileutils'

filename = "C:/Users/drwat/Desktop/somefolder/accountusernames.txt"
times = IO.readlines(filename).size
counter = 0
password = "changethis"

originalFolder = "Release/."

while(counter < times)
    begin
        currentusername = IO.readlines(filename)[counter]

        FileUtils.mkdir currentusername
        FileUtils.cp_r(originalFolder, "#{currentusername}")

        #Put username into auth.json file
        data = File.read("auth.json")
        filtered_data = data.gsub("aaaa", "#{currentusername}")
        File.open("auth.json", "w") do |f|
            f.write(filtered_data)
        end

        #Put password into auth.json file
        data = File.read("auth.json")
        filtered_data = data.gsub("bbbb", "#{password}")
        File.open("auth.json", "w") do |f|
            f.write(filtered_data)
        end

        FileUtils.cp "auth.json", "#{currentusername}/Config"

        #Revert auth.json file back to A's and B's
        data = File.read("auth.json")
        filtered_data = data.gsub("#{currentusername}", "aaaa")
        File.open("auth.json", "w") do |f|
            f.write(filtered_data)
        end
        data = File.read("auth.json")
        filtered_data = data.gsub("#{password}", bbbb)
        File.open("auth.json", "w") do |f|
            f.write(filtered_data)
        end

        counter += 1
    end
end
```

The error I get when I run the program:

```
D:/Installed Programs/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Invalid argument - twitchypair1 (Errno::EINVAL)
        from D:/Installed Programs/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
        from D:/Installed Programs/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:174:in `block in mkdir'
        from D:/Installed Programs/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:173:in `each'
        from D:/Installed Programs/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:173:in `mkdir'
        from D:/somefolder/thiscode.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

I don't know if there is something wrong with my code or my installation of ruby or what. I've tried a few different ways to make it work, such as removing the FileUtils.mkdir line, but I can't get it. That just gives me another error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I haven't done a whole lot with Ruby but it seems very easy to use apart from this.

Also, do "#{currentusername}" and currentusername return the exact same thing?

Comment: `#{x}` and `x` are generally equivalent *if* `x` is a string value. For others it is roughly equivalent to `x.to_s`.

Comment: Also not clear why you have a `begin...end` structure in the middle there with no particular purpose.

Comment: Is it possible you have a file with the name of the directory you're trying to create?

Comment: I'm also not sure why you're using a while loop here when something like: `IO.readlines(filename).chomp.each {|currentusername| ... }` might be cleaner. Also, using http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir it seems you can enable a verbose option. Maybe that will yield some info for the failure.

Comment: @Jim I read your comment and was immediately able to solve my problem. I googled Errno::EINVAL and found out that I needed to add .chomps to the end of IO.readlines(filename). Apparently there is some sort of special character that .chomps removes? Also, I'm fairly new to Ruby, there was a little bit of copy & paste going on here, so I'm sure I don't have the most efficient code. I'll look into .each, I am not familiar with it yet.

Comment: Yup, chomp'ing removes the linefeed on the end of the line (string). So that makes sense now that it wasn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this should work:

```
require 'fileutils'

filename = "C:/Users/drwat/Desktop/somefolder/accountusernames.txt"
times    = IO.readlines(filename).size
counter  = 0
password = "changethis"

originalFolder = "Release/."

IO.readlines(filename).chomp.each \
{|currentusername|
    FileUtils.mkdir currentusername
    ...
}
```

As I mentioned before, it's almost always a good idea to chomp() data in a file to remove that carriage return/linefeed from the source data.